# Add every 100 string keys from dictionary in array of strings with comma separator

Tags: swift, string, dictionary, key

So I have a dictionary with 450 or sometimes 1313 string keys and I want to add all keys in array of strings, so earch string has to contains from 1 to 100 keys it depends how big is the dictionary.
Example if there are 450 keys:

```
let array = ["first 100 keys here comma separated","second 100 keys here comma separated","third 100 keys here comma separated","fourth 100 keys here comma separated","and last 50 keys comma separated"]
```

Comment: Do you have any code already?

Comment: No I only have the keys in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to group your array elements and use map to join your keys using `joined(separator: ", ")`:

```
extension Array {
    func group(of n: IndexDistance) -> Array<Array> {
        return stride(from: 0, to: count, by: n)
        .map { Array(self[$0..<Swift.min($0+n, count)]) }
    }
}
```

---

Testing:

```
let dic = ["f":1,"a":1,"b":1,"c":1,"d":1,"e":1, "g": 1]
let arr = Array(dic.keys).group(of: 2).map{
    $0.joined(separator: ", ")
}
arr  //["b, a", "c, f", "e, g", "d"]
```

Comment: Where I can study about these functions group and map, and play with them in the playground ? From where are you learning Swift ?

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov I have been coding in Swift for more than 3 years, so you will learn this naturally. SO has plenty of examples on how to use them.

Comment: Yes I also programming from the beginning of Swift, but I'm not so deep in the language like you. I already have 5 approved apps in the App Store

Comment: try this https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-guide-to-map-filter-reduce/

Comment: @LeoDabus If you generalize this extension to `RandomAccessCollection`, you won't need to promote `dic.keys` to `Array`