# How to sort a multidimensional character array alphabetically Swift

Tags: swift, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am trying to sort a [[Character]] array that has random characters put in to it so that it is all alphabetical. ex output for right now:

```
["H", "P", "C"]
["F", "K", "V"]
["J", "Y", "B"]
```

I need it to be like this

```
["A", "B", "C"]
["D", "E", "F"]
["G", "H", "I"]
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: How can A be first when it’s not in any of the arrays? Makes no sense.

Comment: It was just a sample of what I needed, I mean that its supposed to be sorted alphabetically

Comment: It's _not_ a sample. Show actual input and actual desired output. We are programmers, not mindreaders. — Okay... So what's the problem? Flatten the arrays, sort, and divide again into threes. What's the hard part for you?

Comment: I didn't think of that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please check :

```
let input = [["H", "P", "C"], ["F", "K", "V"], ["J", "Y", "B"], ["A", "L"]]
var sortedArray = input.flatMap({ $0 }).sorted()

var finalArray:[[String]]=[]
var subArray:[String]=[]
for i in 0..<sortedArray.count {
    subArray.append(sortedArray[i])
    if subArray.count == 3 || i == sortedArray.count-1 {
        finalArray.append(subArray)
        subArray = []
    }
}

print(finalArray) 
// Output : [["A", "B", "C"], ["F", "H", "J"], ["K", "L", "P"], ["V", "Y"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func flattenArray(nestedArray: [[Character]]) -> [[Character]]{

var myFlattendArray = [Character]()
var sortedArray = [[Character]]()

for element in nestedArray{
    if element is [Character]{
        for char in element{
            myFlattendArray.append(char)
        }
    }
}
myFlattendArray = myFlattendArray.sorted(by: {$0 < $1})
var arrayForArray = [Character]()
for i in 0..<myFlattendArray.count{
   if((i % nestedArray.count == 0 && i != 0)){
        sortedArray.append(arrayForArray)
        arrayForArray.removeAll()
   }else if i == myFlattendArray.count - 1{
        arrayForArray.append(myFlattendArray[i])
        sortedArray.append(arrayForArray)
        arrayForArray.removeAll()
   }
   arrayForArray.append(myFlattendArray[i])

}
   return sortedArray
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flatMap to flatten your array, sort it and then you can group using this extension from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46029179/2303865) as follow:

```
extension Array {
    func group(of n: IndexDistance) -> Array<Array> {
        return stride(from: 0, to: count, by: n)
            .map { Array(self[$0..<Swift.min($0+n, count)]) }
    }
}

let arr = [["H", "P", "C"],
           ["F", "K", "V"],
           ["J", "Y", "B"]]

let sorted = arr.flatMap{$0}.sorted().group(of: 3)
sorted  // [["B", "C", "F"], ["H", "J", "K"], ["P", "V", "Y"]]
```